# java stream mutate data with terminal operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

[Java Stream Cheat Sheet](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-streams-cheat-sheet/)

Going by this Cheat sheet for Java Stream - I understand that Java streams cannot mutate data.

For example in the code used below, am I right in saying that - using a forEach terminal operation the data is being mutated?

```
List<Foo> fooList=new ArrayList<>();
fooList.stream()
.filter(foo-> return foo.getSomeBoolean())
.forEach(foo->{
  foo.setSomeBoolean(false);
});
```

I am confused that the forEach terminal operation can have side effects on the data but not mutate the data? 

Could someone explain how the foreach is allowed to mutate the data here?

Comment: Read it more carefully: *This data cannot be mutated. That is to say **the original data structure doesn’t change.*** You're mutating the objects, not the data source.

Comment: From doc of `java.util.stream.Stream`: `declaratively describing their source and the computational operations which will be performed in aggregate on that source`. With `filter` method you transform Stream into another Stream and with `forEach` you iterate all elements in stream. `forEach` is terminal operation.

Comment: The fact that the compiler doesn’t object and even the fact that there is no exception at runtime are no prove that a particular operation is allowed. The only thing that matters is the formal specification. Note that you are not modifying the source collection, but still *may* have interference, if the same `Foo` instance appears multiple times in the source `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mutate fooList, but you *can* perform side-effects on the elements using terminal operations. As the cheat sheet says, a stream is a pipe-line, not a data structure. You cannot mutate something that is not a data structure, but you can manipulate the individual elements that are flowing through the pipeline.